# JSON Row Formatting Display Icon based on column value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I am working on some custom JSON using the "rowFormatter" view formatting schema. I want to display an Icon depending on the value in another Column.

My conditional statement is not working. Any help is appreciated.

```
"children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "txtContent": "[!DataDomain.DisplayName]",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "block",
                      "color": "#333333",
                      "text-align": "left",
                      "font-size": "12px",
                      "font-weight": "bold",
                      "padding-top": "10px"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "attributes": {
                      "iconName": "=if ([$DataDomain] == 'Property', 'CityNext', if([$DataDomain]== 'Tenant', 'People', if ([$DataDomain] == 'Financial', 'Financial', if ([$DataDomain] == 'Client', 'AccountManagement', if ([$DataDomain] == 'Employee', 'WorkforceManagement', if ([$DataDomain] == 'Market/External', 'Source'))))))",
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "display": "inline"
                    }

                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "txtContent": "=if ([$DataDomain] == '', '–', [$DataDomain])",
                    "style": { 
                    "display": "inline",
                      "font-size": "12px",
                      "padding-left": "5px"
                    }
                  }
              ]
```

Comment: What is the data type of your "DataDomain" column? Are you getting any syntax error or it's just that icon is not rendering?

Comment: I am not getting a syntax error. The icons are just not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
"iconName": "=if([$DataDomain] == 'Property', 'CityNext', if([$DataDomain] == 'Tenant', 'People', if([$DataDomain] == 'Financial', 'Financial', if([$DataDomain] == 'Client', 'AccountManagement', if([$DataDomain] == 'Employee', 'WorkforceManagement', if([$DataDomain] == 'Market/External', 'Source', ''))))))"
```

Also, make sure you are using correct **internal name** of your "DataDomain" column in JSON. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Documentation**:

1. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)
2. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: This did not work unfortunately.

Comment: What is the column type/data type of your `[$DataDomain]` column?

Comment: Are you using correct internal name? Are you able to see the "DisplayName" of column correctly?

Comment: Yes. I am using the correct internal name.  I am referencing the same column in the "span" immediately below the one with I am having the issue with  as you will see in the original code snippet I posted. Is it not possible to use an if statement with the "iconName" attribute? I used a "if" logic statement in another view on "background-color" so I figured it should work with "iconName".

Comment: `if` expressions work with iconName as well (check 2nd link in my answer). If everything is correct, it should work for you. Is this column added in your list view? To reference the column in JSON, it should be added to the list view. Also, what is the data type of column? Single line of text or choice or something else?

Comment: It have added the field to my list view. It is a choice column.  Do I need to do something like [$DataDomain].value or @DataDomain.value?

Comment: For choice field, no need to use `.value` or anything. It should work as you already written.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below column formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "color": "#333333",
        "text-align": "left",
        "font-size": "12px",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "padding-top": "10px",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if([$DataDomain] == 'Property', 'CityNext', if([$DataDomain]  == 'Tenant', 'People', if([$DataDomain] == 'Financial', 'Client', if([$DataDomain] == 'Client', 'AccountManagement',if([$DataDomain] == 'Employee','WorkforceManagement',if([$DataDomain] == 'Market/External','Source',''))))))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=if ([$DataDomain] == '', '–', [$DataDomain])"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @EchoDu_MSFT. The issue was not when using the Column formatting schema  . I am using the using the row formatting schema. However I think I have gotten it to work? I used the  columnFormatterReference to reference the column formatting in the list view. and it works.             {
                "elmType": "span",
                "columnFormatterReference": "[$DataDomain]",
                "style": {
                  "display": "inline",
                  "padding-top": "10px"
                }
              }